# Simple javascript onSubmit won't work

Tags: javascript, forms

I am trying to redirect to google search on simple form submit but it won't work. Here is my code stripped:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function search(){
alert("in function!");
var a = document.getElementById("searchbox").value;
a = "http://www.google.com/#q=" + a;
a = a.replace(" ","+");
alert(a);
document.location = a;
}

</script>

<form method="post" action="#" onSubmit="search()">

<input type="text" id="searchbox" />

</form>
```

I get no alerts at all.

Comment: How are you submitting the form? There is no submit button. It works with one: http://jsfiddle.net/BmaD6/

Comment: The diagnosis "it won't work" is not useful.  What did you expect this script to do?  What does it do instead?

Comment: How is the onSubmit Handler, ie. search(), being activated. Via a button. Via javascript. If it is not being activated then there will be no alert!

Comment: @Felix Kling: I press enter on input box, it can tell it submit by the way in which page reloads.
cdhowie: I expect it to open google searh for a entered term, it won't
Brett: I submit the form by pressing <return> on input box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things, first it works fine for me, http://jsfiddle.net/LzwAt/1/
Make sure you have the javascript in the head tag of the file, and don't forget the submit button ;).

Also, if you just want to submit to google you could always just do:

```
<form action="http://google.com/search" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="q" />
    <input type="submit" name="go" value="Search">
</form>
```

EDIT:
try this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function search()
            {
                alert("in function!");
                var a = document.getElementById("searchbox").value;
                a = "http://www.google.com/#q=" + a;
                a = a.replace(" ","+");
                alert(a);
                document.location = a;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="#" onSubmit="search();return false;">
            <input type="text" id="searchbox" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I didn't use jsfiddle before, so I can't quite understand how that works. I can't use your example because I need to modify search string before searching in google. What I finally want to achive is, a input box where I type things, press enter and get google search by adding site:bysite.com at the end of query string.

Comment: Added a bit more, the `return false;`, so that the form didn't redirect you back after the js redirects you to google